# How to exploit periodicity to reduce noise of a signal?

Tags: c++, r, matlab, signal-processing, fft

100 periods have been collected from a 3 dimensional periodic signal. The wavelength slightly varies. The noise of the wavelength follows Gaussian distribution with zero mean. A good estimate of the wavelength is known, that is not an issue here. The noise of the amplitude may not be Gaussian and may be contaminated with outliers.

**How can I compute a single period that approximates 'best' all of the collected 100 periods?**

Time-series, ARMA, ARIMA, Kalman Filter, autoregression and autocorrelation seem to be keywords here.

**UPDATE 1:** I have no idea how time-series models work. Are they prepared for varying wavelengths? Can they handle non-smooth true signals? If a time-series model is fitted, can I compute a 'best estimate' for a single period? How?

**UPDATE 2:** A related question is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2572444/341970). Speed is not an issue in my case. Processing is done off-line, after all periods have been collected.

**Origin of the problem:** I am measuring acceleration during human steps at 200 Hz. After that I am trying to double integrate the data to get the vertical displacement of the center of gravity. Of course the noise introduces a HUGE error when you integrate twice. I would like to exploit periodicity to reduce this noise. Here is a crude graph of the actual data (y: acceleration in g, x: time in second) of 6 steps corresponding to 3 periods (1 left and 1 right step is a period):

[image: human steps]

My interest is now purely theoretical, as http://jap.physiology.org/content/39/1/174.abstract gives a pretty good recipe what to do.

Comment: can you supply some dummy data to illustrate the problem you want to estimate the period from?

Comment: Do you know precisely what the variation in period is?  Or is it essentially random?

Comment: Is `spectrum` in package `stats` of any use? - ?spectrum

Comment: @Ali It's nice of you to put a bounty on this question.  But it is still unclear to me what exactly you are trying to do.  As the question stands, there are at least two possible interpretations.  The first is "how do I fit a time-series model".  The second is "how do I determine the wavelenght of my signal".  Can you please clarify and supply some dummy data?

Comment: @Andrie The approximate wavelength is known and can be improved further easily, it is not an issue here. I have no idea how time-series models work. Are they prepared for varying wavelengths? If a time-series model is fitted, can I compute a smoothed period? How?

Comment: @Ali: I think a lot of the people here are capable of explaining time-series analysis, smoothing etc. However, it is not very clear what exactly you're trying to achieve, which is why you don't have many answers. If you post some sample data and explain what exactly you want to do (I don't care if it's a crude graph, as long as I can understand it), it'll get the point across better and you'll attract more answers. If you can't post some data, could you draw what you have in mind and post that as an image? If that's not possible, math equations will do (I prefer this as there is no ambiguity).

Comment: @yoda I have added a graph of the actual data. I doubt that it helps. The actual dataset is very large, I am sampling at 200 Hz.

Comment: Question is still too vague and unfocused for SO. Try better http://stats.stackexchange.com/  or read some book about time series and signal processing

Comment: @leonbloy What further information would make the question easier to understand / clear? Yes, perhaps the question should be migrated to stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: -1: Interesting but off topic.

Comment: @Troubadour -1 is not helping. What do you suggest? Should this question be migrated to stats.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @Ali: Eh, its borderline on-topic.  Also, you have a bounty and people have spent time to help you answer this.  I'm really not in favor of migration.

Comment: In passing, the empirical mode decomposition (EMD) is a time-domain signals processing technique that extracts periodic features from signals. There's a lot of information about the EMD on the web, or you could read S2.3 of [my thesis.](http://www.penwatch.net/files/thesis/Online_Empirical_Mode_Decomposition_Li-aung_Yip_2010.pdf).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have used wavelets for noise suppression with similar signal measured from cows during walking. 
I'm don't think the noise is so much of a problem here and the biggest peaks represent actual changes in the acceleration during walking.

I suppose that the angle of the leg and thus accelerometer changes during your experiment and you need to account for that in order to calculate the distance i.e you need to know what is the orientation of the accelerometer in each time step. See e.g this [technical note](http://www.vti.fi/midcom-serveattachmentguid-9cdff49ade3611ddb72c3b87f201104c104c/an50_sca3000_accelerometer_in_velocity_distance_and_energya-s.pdf) for one to account for angle.

If you need get accurate measures of the position the best solution would be to get an accelerometer with a magnetometer, which also measures orientation. Something like this should work: http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10321.

**EDIT**: I have looked into this a bit more in the last few days because a similar project is in my to do list as well... We have not used gyros in the past, but we are doing so in the next project.

The inaccuracy in the positioning doesn't come from the white noise, but from the inaccuracy and drift of the gyro. And the error then accumulates very quickly due to the double integration. Intersense has a product called [Navshoe](http://www.intersense.com/pages/17/17), that addresses this problem by zeroing the error after each step (see [this paper](http://www.intersense.com/uploads/documents/Pedestrian_Tracking_with_Shoe-Mounted_Inertial_Sensors.pdf)). And [this](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/techreports/UCAM-CL-TR-696.pdf) is a good introduction to inertial navigation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sorry I could not reply earlier. I am already using accelerometers, gyroscopes and magnetometer for measuring orientation, I am using a Shimmer 2r device. How did you use wavelets for noise suppresion?

Comment: I used wavelet shrinkage: http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=wmtsa:wavShrink.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! You might find useful this one: http://jap.physiology.org/content/39/1/174.abstract. Although they measured force, it's probably easy to adopt for acceleration, assuming you are using gyroscopes too.

Comment: Hi Ali, thanks for the paper and the Shrimmer seems like an interesting product. I have updated my answer a bit and I hope you find it useful.

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to compute the displacement of the center of gravity during steady walking, so navigation does not apply here. Anyhow, the links are very useful, please leave them there. Unless another, better answer is given, I will award you the bounty manually.

Comment: Hi Matti! I am giving you the bounty so nothing is lost of it. You might be interested in drift cancellation for gyroscopes: http://gentlenav.googlecode.com/files/DCMDraft2.pdf . Works like a charm for us. As for my original question, I will try to migrate it to stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the bounty and the link! Looks very interesting.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts to answer my question and for the links. (Some others 'helped' me by downvoting my question...)

Answer (score 2):

Periodic signal without noise has the following property:

```
f(a) = f(a+k), where k is the wavelength.
```

Next bit of information that is needed is that your signal is composed of separate samples. Every bit of information you've collected are based on samples, which are values of f() function. From 100 samples, you can get the mean value:

```
1/n * sum(s_i), where i is in range [0..n-1] and n = 100.
```

This needs to be done for every dimension of your data. If you use 3d data, it will be applied 3 times. Result would be (x,y,z) points. You can find value of s_i from the periodic signal equation simply by doing

```
s_i(a).x = f(a+k*i).x
s_i(a).y = f(a+k*i).y
s_i(a).z = f(a+k*i).z
```

If the wavelength is not accurate, this will give you additional source of error or you'll need to adjust it to match the real wavelength of each period. Since

`k*i = k+k+...+k`

if the wavelength varies, you'll need to use
  `k_1+k_2+k_3+...+k_i`
instead of k*i.
Unfortunately with errors in wavelength, there will be big problems keeping this k_1..k_i chain in sync with the actual data. You'd actually need to know how to regognize the starting position of each period from your actual data. Possibly need to mark them by hand.

Now, all the mean values you calculated would be functions like this:

`m(a) :: R->(x,y,z)`

Now this is a curve in 3d space. More complex error models will be left as an excersize for the reader.

Comment: So, basically what you suggest is to cut the data into periods by hand... Isn't there a model that can handle noise in the wavelength? I find this hard to believe. Thanks anyhow!

Comment: What about circular regression?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a copy of Curve Fitting Toolbox, localized regression might be a good choice.

1. Curve Fitting Toolbox supports both lowess and loess localized regression models for curve and curve fitting.
2. There is an option for robust localized regression

The following blog post shows how to use cross validation to estimate an optimzal spaning parameter for a localized regression model, as well as techniques to estimate confidence intervals using a bootstrap.

http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/01/13/data-driven-fitting/

Comment: Thanks. Does lowess make any use of periodicity? It seems to me it assumes nothing about the signal.

Comment: ?Ali: `loess` just fits a smoothed curve made up of lots of quadratic curves (or other polynomials) fitted to sections of the data and joined together.  It does not consider periodicity.

Comment: @Richie Cotton Yes, that's what I thought.